Recoding an entire data frame using label-value pairs stored in a different dataframe
Suppose I have a dataframe:
df <- data.frame(
  x = c("Yes","No","Yes","Don't Know"),
  y = c("Male","Female","Refused","Male"),
  z = c("Employed", "Unemployed","Employed","Employed")
)

I want to recode the values in the entire dataframe to numeric values and have the codes stored in a separate dataframe:
codes <- data.frame(
  variable = c(rep("x",3),rep("y",3),rep("z",2)),
  labels = c("Yes","No","Don't Know","Male","Female","Refused","Employed", "Unemployed"),
  codes = c(1,2,98,1,2,99,1,2)
)

I want to output to look like:
> df
   x  y z
1  1  1 1
2  2  2 2
3  1 99 1
4 98  1 1

How can I approach this problem? A tidyverse solution would be very helpful.

pivot your df to long format and then left_join with codes.  If necessary, pivot back to wide format.

An option would be to bring the data in long format join with codes dataset and move it back to wide format.
Using tidyverse this can be done as following :
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  left_join(codes, join_by(name == variable, value == labels)) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = codes, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest_longer(everything())

# A tibble: 4 × 3
#      x     y     z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1
#2     2     2     2
#3     1    99     1
#4    98     1     1


In tidyverse, you can try
df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~{with(
        filter(codes, variable == cur_column()),
        codes[match(.x, labels)]) }))

which gives
   x  y z
1  1  1 1
2  2  2 2
3  1 99 1
4 98  1 1


Loop through columns, find matches on labels, get corresponding codes:
sapply(names(df), function(i){
  ix <- which(codes$variable == i)
  codes[ ix, "codes" ][ match(df[[ i ]], codes[ ix, "labels"]) ]})
#       x  y z
# [1,]  1  1 1
# [2,]  2  2 2
# [3,]  1 99 1
# [4,] 98  1 1


Use Map function as below:
df2 = df
df2[] = Map(\(h, k) k$codes[match(h, k$labels)], df, split(codes, ~variable))

   x  y z
1  1  1 1
2  2  2 2
3  1 99 1
4 98  1 1


Another simple solution using a named vector:
a <- codes$codes
names(a) <- codes$labels
apply(df, 2, \(x) a[x])

      x  y z
[1,]  1  1 1
[2,]  2  2 2
[3,]  1 99 1
[4,] 98  1 1

More robust (and verbose) solution would be:
v <- tapply(codes$codes, codes$variable, c)
n <- tapply(codes$labels, codes$variable, c)
as.data.frame(Map(\(u, v, w) {a<-u;names(a)<-v;unname(a[w])}, v, n, df))


library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

lookup <- map(split(codes, ~ variable), \(dat) pull(dat, codes, labels))

df |>
  mutate(across(everything(), \(x) lookup[[cur_column()]][x]))
#    x  y z
# 1  1  1 1
# 2  2  2 2
# 3  1 99 1
# 4 98  1 1

